# Print screen has red theme

Tags: windows-10, print-screen

recently in windows 10 I faced a new problem (not happened before). When I use PrtScr and paste the clipboard in Photoshop (Also tried Microsoft Paint), the image has RED theme. I have checked many color profiles when cerating a new document using Ctrl+N but the result has red theme yet.

Does it relating to hardware settings or software settings? Why this wasn't happen before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved after updating windows 10. The last updates I have installed were **kb4516058** , **kb4514357**, **kb4516115** however I am not sure which one actually solved the problem because there is no details about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but it might be due to this issue recently reported regarding a Windows update.  Red screen of death is also known to occur due to hardware issues but is more commonly associated with hardware failure due to overclocking, so your issue sounds more likely to have been due to the recent updates.

Comment: Not sure why linking isn't working from mobile browser or just isn't displaying correctly on my screen, but here's the link: www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2019/09/10/microsoft-windows-10-update-problem-red-screen-warning-upgrade-windows-10/